# How to substract two similar audios, and play the difference(in wav.file or mp3. file)

Tags: audio

I have two audios, the original audio A and the new audio B, B is made from A by adding some noise, now, is it possible that I want to extract the noise and play it? By playing it, I need the noise to be transmitted into audio files, not the graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two sources are bit-identical other than the added signal in B...

... then simply invert the phase of A & add it to B.

This will completely remove A from B.